# 192.168.1.2 domain is not a trusted domain G+ Login on Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, google-signin

I would like to test the G+ login with device live reloader feature on Ionic 3. But it says `192.168.1.2` `domain is not a trusted domain`. I have added above domain to the firebase console as shown below. Could you tell me why it doesn't allow to use that domain?

[image]

I saw above error on my android device when I used this CLI `ionic cordova run android --prod --device --livereload`. This CLI generates above domain id (i.e. `192.168.1.2`) on my android device. I have used remote debugging with chrome here.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: I saw above error on my android device when I used this CLI `ionic cordova run android --prod --device --livereload`. This CLI generates above domain id (i.e. `192.168.1.2`) @bojeil